# Disable cache on specific domains?

Tags: firefox-addon

Is there a good way to disable cache for specific domains? For example, anytime I start building a new website can I block just that domain from caching? I would prefer the rest of the internet to be cache-able.

I am currently using Firefox Web Developer Toolbar addon to disable cache, is there any better plugins?

Comment: You'd need to modify the addon's source code to do that; IIRC Web Developer Toolbar either disables all caching, or doesn't interfere with it.

Comment: Add-ons cannot override the cache settings for a web page, only disable the cache globally. So @Spliffster is correct, the web page needs to send the correct headers, that's the only way. Maybe do that in some kind of "debug mode" that is switched off later.

Answer (score 6):

Built-in Firefox Developer Tool has a features to disable cache for tabs where this toolbox is open.

[image: Firefox Developer Tools Settings]

> Disable cache: disable the browser cache to simulate first-load performance. From Firefox 33 onwards this setting persists, meaning that if it is set, caching will be disabled whenever you reopen the devtools. Caching is re-enabled when the devtools are closed.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Tools_Toolbox

Unfortunatley it's not per domain, but maybe this is better than Web Developer Toolbar.

Answer (score 2):

You can send specific headers from your web application to prevent the browser from caching. You might send these headers only to your ip or browsers where a certain cookie is set.

Return these headers to prevent a browser from caching your content:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
```

Expires should be a date in the past.

Answer (score 2):

The [Charles Web Debugging Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) is a good way to disable cache for specific domains. Just go to the Tools menu, then select No Caching. A window will open that lets you specify which locations to prevent caching on.

Charles is a proxy so you can use it to control the caching in all of your web browsers - Firefox, Chrome, IE, whatever you use!

Answer (score 0):

I usually use a rewrite rule allowing `/static/${NUMBERS}/directory/file.js` to be served from `/static/directory/file.js`. Large files are treated separately (mp4, zip...). With PHP i set ${NUMBERS} to the UNIX_TIMESTAMP for development, and to VERSION_NUMBER for production. Now development is always downloaded but cdnjs almost never.

Comment: In php you can use something like: `/static/directory/file.js?v=<?php echo filemtime('/static/directory/file.js'); ?>`.