# Prevent Firefox from caching localhost?

Tags: firefox, caching

I've been curious to try switching to Firefox Quantum from Chrome, but for web development have hit a major obstacle that I have not been able to easily resolve –– it's caching my localhost files so when I attempt to load various ember applications at localhost:4200 I end up viewing a cached application different than the one that is currently running.

Is there a way to disable caching for localhost in Firefox? And/or how to developers normally work with Firefox in this regard?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable cache on specific domains?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810966/disable-cache-on-specific-domains)

Comment: Just wanted to also add that one could as well manually clear caches from `menu > settings > privacy & security > clear data`

Comment: You could also use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. For some reason it works flawlessly

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> And/or how to developers normally work with Firefox in this regard?

I tend to use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> to do hard reload (ignores cache). Pretty standard for all browsers.

Since there is no native way to configure for individual domains, you could write a Browser Extension that can intercept responses via the [`webRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) API (see for example [`onHeadersReceived`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest/onHeadersReceived)) by overriding cache headers for a selected domain (you may even be able to [find one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=cache) already in existence).

Or simply configure settings in developer tools to ignore cache when toolbox is open:

[image: snapshot]

There is also the [Forget Button](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/forget-button-quickly-delete-your-browsing-history) that can be dragged into the toolbar from customize.

[image: forget button]

Answer (score 5):

Set the HTTP Cache-Control response header to `max-age=0` in your application.

Comment: Haa! Saved me hours. Thanks : )